# mysql query to show results above an average that uses two tables in its sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a query that displays only contract costs above average along with the contract id and I create my average with this:

```
SELECT AVG(average_cost)
FROM (
SELECT SUM(contracts.hours*staff.rate) AS average_cost
FROM contracts
INNER JOIN staff ON contracts.staff_id = staff.staff_id
GROUP BY contracts.contract_id
) AS inner;
```

I would like the results to show contract_id as well as group by it, even if it all it shows is the contract_id for the results above the average. Just having a hard time getting a query to show results above average with this average that is more complicated than I'm use to. Help appreciated, thanks.

edit* with some sample data, the tables are more complex than this but I hope this helps with some understanding

```
contracts

contract_id   hours   staff_id
55            30       10
45            25       11
43            30       12
41            12       11
67            20       12   
49            20       13


staff

staff_id   rate
10         50 
11         45
12         80
13         45
```

So the average contract cost of above is 1,344.167 or there abouts. For this example I would want the results to show the contract_id for the contracts that cost above the average.

```
results

contract_id   
55            
43            
67
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It would help make the question clearer.

Comment: Ill do that now for you sorry

Comment: As for the result, the other user who commented, KKK, would give the result in the format I would like just that it needs to only show results above the average, not all averages

Comment: what will be the expected output?

Comment: I added an example output to the sample in the main post. So the results would show at least the contract_id of all the contracts that are above the average contract cost, which is gotten from hours*rate in the SUM that I posted. If the results also had the cost of contracts above average like KKKs post that's fine too

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT c.contract_id, SUM(c.hours*s.rate) AS cost
FROM contracts c INNER JOIN
     staff s
     ON c.staff_id = s.staff_id
GROUP BY c.contract_id
HAVING cost > (SELECT AVG(average_cost)
               FROM (SELECT SUM(c.hours*s.rate) AS average_cost
                     FROM contracts c INNER JOIN
                          staff s
                          ON c.staff_id = s.staff_id
                     GROUP BY c.contract_id
                    ) sc
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

As much I understand with your question, I think you are looking for this:

```
   select contract_id
from contracts join staff on (contracts.staff_id = staff.staff_id)
where (hours*rate) > 
(select avg(hours*rate)
from contracts join staff on (contracts.staff_id = staff.staff_id)
)
```

Comment: Almost exactly this, except I only want results to show that are above the average, not just the average of every contract_id. If that makes sense

Comment: Do you to get the average of all the contractar.

Comment: Sorry, so I used your query and it gives the sum of hours*rates but no averages. So the result im looking for would be displaying only the results that are higher average than the average of all those rates. Ive updated main post if that helps

Comment: I have updated the answer, Check out the code here for example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e24a8d/13

Answer (score 0):

I have my example that can help you:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, invoice_amount
        FROM students 
        INNER JOIN invoices 
        ON students.id_student = invoices.id_student
        WHERE invoice_amount > (select avg(invoice_amount) from invoices)
```